# Every diagonalizable matrix is uniquely diagonalizable that is if $A=PDP^{-1}=QDQ^{-1}$, then $P=Q$. This is false, but why?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I know that this condition only holds true to a certain extent, but there are counterexamples. I know that eigenvalues can be rearranged as long as it is done so diagonally, but I am struggling to figure out an example that disproves the $P=Q$ condition. Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider $A=D=I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, let's consider $3\times 3$ matrices only. The same method can be extended to $n\times n$ matrices,  $n\in \mathbb N$. 
Suppose that $A$ is diagonalizable matrix.Hence, there exist invertible matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A=PDP^{-1}$

> $AP=PD\implies [Ap_1, Ap_2, Ap_3]=[\lambda_1p_1,
> \lambda_2p_2,\lambda_3 p_3]\implies$ Columns of $P$ must be
> eigenvectors, which are of course not unique because if $p_1$ is an
> eigenvector so is $\alpha p_1$ for any constant $\alpha$.

Using the above, you can create counterexamples.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in particular, for *any* invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$, we have $I = P I P^{-1} = Q I Q^{-1}$.